# Running eslint from subdirectory

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, devops, eslint, eslintrc

My project contains a subproject with its own `.eslintrc` (i.e. under `./path/to/subproject`)
I'm trying to run `lint` but it either goes to the root project `.eslintrc` file or it can't find the `.eslintrc` file
I've tried the following configurations in `package.json`:

```
cd path/to/subproject
```

and:

```
"lint": "tsc && eslint -c .eslintrc.js ./**/*.ts --"
```

or

```
"lint": "tsc && eslint -c ./.eslintrc.js ./**/*.ts --"
```

Also tried in root dir:

```
"lint": "tsc && eslint -c path/to/subproject/.eslintrc.js ./**/*.ts --"
```

or

```
"lint": "tsc && eslint -c .eslintrc.js ./**/*.ts --"
```

with

```
npm run lint --prefix path/to/subproject/
```

But it keeps referring the root project `.eslintrc` file:

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 6.4.0.

ESLint couldn't find the config "configname" to extend from. Please check that the name of the config is correct.

The config "configname" was referenced from the config file in "/home/vsts/work/1/s/.eslintrc.js". <-- this is the wrong .eslintrc
```

The environment is Azure DevOps pipeline with Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: isn't the eslint a json file? like `eslint -c ~/my-eslint.json file.js`

Comment: can be `js` file as well, see here: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So it looks like `eslint` supports this
What I had to do is add `"root": true` to my eslint config file, it now looks something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    "extends": [
        "configname"
    ],
    "root": true
}
```

See documentation [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy)