# How to block vscode typescript file importing from a folder it should not?

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, visual-studio-code

We use typescript & webpack. All of the code is in one repo. The product is a game thus the states and objects need to be shared so it has 3 different main folders.

The shared code is used both on the backend and the frontend. The server code should never be imported by shared or client otherwise it creates a security risk.

We had server code accidentally imported previously which resulted in a security issue where we needed to change all the keys. We don't have any system set up in place to prevent this from happening again.

One method is to break up the server & client into 2 different projects, but that would take a lot of time and increase the complexity too much.

Another method is to run a script that detects if server code has been imported into Shared or Client. I can do it with python and make it run when we push a code. But with all the functions of VSCode I'm sure they probably have such a thing. Or maybe npm has such a library.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Either use the tsconfig.json project references feature or have multiple tsconfig.json files that extend a shared common configuration. Without knowing more about your actual code it's hard to so which approach is preferable

Comment: I've written custom eslint rules in the past to enforce similar import conventions in the past and found it to work well

Comment: @Michael that can definitely be effective and I considered suggesting it but I don't think it will have the desired impact on intellisense suggesting modules to import

Comment: This is true, however it should give a squiggly line, and ci pipeline failure which was enough for my use case. I think the most effective/safe option would be to structure the shared code as an npm package that was consumed by the client/server. This could be done as a monorepo using something like lerna, or simply as separate repositories

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use [ESLint](https://eslint.org/), which has [a plugin for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) as well, you can use [cascading configurations](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy) along with [restricted imports](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports). Autocomplete will still suggest the imports, but at least they will instantly be marked as red and squigly.

The directory setup remains the same as it is, with the addition of configuration files:

```
code
├ client
│ └ .eslintrc
├ server
│ └ .eslintrc
└ .eslintrc
```

The key note here is that the root `.eslintrc` contains your primary rules, whereas the `.eslintrc` files in subdirectories can extend it as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58259491/1470607). You can find more information on how to configure that [in the docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy).

This will allow you to set up [restricted imports](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports) which support both path-based and pattern-based restrictions:

```json
"no-restricted-imports": ["error", {
    "paths": ["import1", "import2"],
    "patterns": ["import1/private/*", "import2/*", "!import2/good"]
}]
```

You can then disallow server code imports in the client and shared subdirectories.